# let $A,G,H$ be the AM, GM and HM, of two distinct reals. Then Find the interval in which the roots of $Ax^2-2Gx+H=0$ lie.

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $A,G,H$ be the AM, GM and HM, of two distinct reals. Then Find the interval in which the roots of $Ax^2-2Gx+H=0$ lie.

Let the number be $p,q$

so$
A= \frac{\left(p+q\right)}{2}$

$G=\sqrt{pq}= \frac{2A}{G^2}$

$H=2\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}\right)$

The roots are , therefore $\frac{\left(-2G\pm\sqrt{4G^2-4AH}\right)}{2A}$

or $\frac{\left(G\ \pm\sqrt{G^2-\frac{2A^2}{G^2}}\right)}{A}$

Not sure what to do beyond this, would appreciate some inputs( Just realised I probably have to use $AM\geq GM$, not sure how to use it though

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of HM is incorrect.
$$HM = \frac{2}{\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}}$$

So, the $4G^2-4AH$ part becomes $0$.

Hence, it has a repeated root which is $\frac{G}{2A}$ or $\frac{\sqrt{pq}}{p+q}$

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $p, q > 0$.  Then your [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) should be
$$H = \frac{2}{\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}} = \frac{2pq}{p+q} = \frac{G^2}{A}.$$

The roots of $A x^2 - 2Gx + H = 0$ are
$$x = \frac{2G \pm \sqrt{4G^2 - 4A H}}{2A} = \frac{G \pm \sqrt{G^2 - AH}}{A} = \frac{G}{A}.$$

So $x = G/A$ is a double root, and we want to find the range of $G/A$ for such $p,q$.  Since the AM-GM inequality states that $A \ge G \ge 0$, with equality occurring if $p = q$, it follows that the range must be a subset of $x \in (0, 1]$.  The value $x = 0$ cannot be attained because $G > 0$ whenever $p, q > 0$.  (Although the problem statement does not seem to explicitly require $p, q > 0$, we take it as such.)  We can arbitrarily choose $q = 1$ to find
$x = \frac{2\sqrt{p}}{p+1}$ and this clearly has the limit
$$\lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{p}}{2(p+1)} = 0,$$
so the desired interval is $(0,1]$.